# Netty with TLS compression (not HTTP)?

Tags: ssl, compression, netty

I'm writing a server to receive data over TLS from an existing application that I can not modify. Using Netty, is it possible for the server to request TLS compression? Note, this is not HTTP over TLS, so HTTP based compression is not relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a high chance that burning a bit extra bandwidth is cheaper than burning those extra cpu cycles and memory usage used by compression and more "secure". One of the reasons why you see compression disabled by default pretty much everywhere. Are you absolutely sure you _need_ ssl compression? Do you have low bandwidth, bad RTT?

Comment: Hi Alen. Yeah, my server is pretty huge - 48 core with 128GB RAM, but I receive data that is highly compressible (better than 15:1 gzip) in high volume from many remote systems connected over WAN/VPN. Of course, compressing at the VPN layer won't work because TLS is by nature highly entropic. The senders generally have CPU to spare. Since I can't change the sender implementation, I was hoping to sneak some basic compression in there via TLS. :)

Answer (score -1):

Just add the SslHandler to the ChannelPipeline to enable TLS/SSL. Piece of cake ;)

Comment: Hi Norman, I'm wondering about TLS compression specifically, not SSL encryption in general. Cheers,